# Scala syntactic sugar for transparently invoking a unary apply on a companion object

Tags: scala, syntactic-sugar

```
class OpenNLPAnnotator extends ThreadLocal[OpenNLPAnnotatorInstance] {
  override def initialValue = new OpenNLPAnnotatorInstance
}

object OpenNLPAnnotator {
  private lazy val ann_ = new OpenNLPAnnotator
  private def ann = ann_
  def apply = ann.get()
}
```

Is there any way for me to get the TLV by doing `OpenNLPAnnotator.someMethodOnTheTLV` ? I have to write `OpenNLPAnnotator.apply.someMethodOnTheTLV`

**edit**

Based on the answers below i'm thinking something like this would be nicest

```
object OpenNLPAnnotator {
  private lazy val ann_ = new OpenNLPAnnotator
  private def ann = ann_
  def apply() = ann.get()
  def annotator = ann.get
}
```

Then I could just do `annotator.whatever`.

That would require an import of course, so unless I put it in a package object it's swings and round-a-bouts. Though I haven't used package objects yet and do not understand the ins and outs.

Comment: you probably should find a better question title

Comment: Sigh, everyone is so serious. truthfully I can't think of one that isn't overly descriptive. I am asking about syntactic-sugar. Sugar is sweet, and the questions is very simple. Can't we lighten SO up a bit ?

Comment: There you go. Question is now in line with serious business policy :D

Comment: good job ;) have an upvote

Comment: Note that you could rename `apply` method while importing it: `import OpenNLPAnnotator.{apply => annotator}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to call `apply` method implicitly is to add parentheses after object name like this:

```
OpenNLPAnnotator().someMethodOnTheTLV
```

But you have to change `apply` method declaration (add parentheses):

```
def apply() = ann.get()
```

#### Nasty hack

You could create an implicit conversion from `OpenNLPAnnotator.type` to `OpenNLPAnnotator` like this:

```
implicit def nastyHack(o: OpenNLPAnnotator.type): OpenNLPAnnotator = o.apply
```

So you could call all methods of `OpenNLPAnnotator` on companion object.

`OpenNLPAnnotator.someMethodOnTheTLV` will be converted to this:

```
nastyHack(OpenNLPAnnotator).someMethodOnTheTLV
```

**Note (in response to your edit):**

You could rename apply method while importing it:

`import OpenNLPAnnotator.{apply => annotator}`

Comment: Hmm yes I could do that. I suppose slick does things this way for resolving calls to the drivers.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Wait for me to rewrite [autoproxy](https://github.com/scala-incubator/autoproxy-plugin/wiki) using macros (it'll be done around the same time that scala 2.11.0-RC1 is released)
2. Use a different pattern!

Did you know that singletons can inherit from their companions?

```
class OpenNLPAnnotator extends ThreadLocal[OpenNLPAnnotatorInstance] {
  override def initialValue = new OpenNLPAnnotatorInstance
}

object OpenNLPAnnotator extends OpenNLPAnnotator {
  def apply = this.get()
}
```